# linked list insert function recursively c++

Tags: c++

I'm writing an insert function recursively for adding an element to the list.The problem is when I run the program and trying to insert, it just inserts once, then at the second time it breaks and has a bug. 
Any suggestions, Thanx

helper function:

```
 void List::insertHelper(Node* list, int number)
        {
            if(list->next != NULL)
            {
                insertHelper(list->next, number);
            }
            else
            {
                list->next = new Node;
                list->next->data = number;
            }

        }
```

this function when I call the recursive one:

```
void List::insert( int d)
    { 
        if( head == NULL)
        {
            head = new Node;
            head->data = d;
        }
        else
        {
        insertHelper(head, d);
        }   

    }
```

Comment: Got something that *compiles* ? There is no `Insert` function in this code yet it is called from `List::insert`, nor is there a class/struct called `Node`, nor a global called `head`. Post the *real* code please.

Comment: Insert function is the insertHelper. thx

Comment: My psychic debugger tells me the constructor for `Node` never sets `Node::next` to NULL, and clearly the rest of this code doesn't either. Your `Node::Node()` constructor should take a single data element and initialize both the `data` member and `next`, such as `Node::Node(int data) : data(data), next(NULL) {}`

Answer (score 1):

You problem is the absence of the following:

```
list->next->next = NULL;
```

in the else part of your insertHelper. As for "suggestions" part, avoid processing lists recursively if you can help it. Your (future) coworkers won't appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
void List::insertHelper(Node* list, int number)
        {
            if(list->next != NULL)
            {
                insertHelper(list->next, number);
            }
            else
            {
                list->next = new Node;
                list->next->data = number;
                list->next->next=NULL; // You are missing this line.... becuase of this.. new nodes next remains as dangling pointer instead of null.. 
            }

        }
```

Comment: +1 (though it is actually an *indeterminate pointer*, not a dangling pointer. A dangler is a pointer that was at one time valid, then released/freed, leaving something that is then invalid). Also, a decent constructor would better address this, as it would ensure *all* instances of `Node` have an initialized pointer; not just the one created here.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you insert a new node you have to set the next value of that new node to NULL. Otherwise your insertHelper will get some junk pointer value each time you call it.

Here is the modified code.

```
void List::insertHelper(Node* list, int number)
    {
        if(list->next != NULL)
        {
            insertHelper(list->next, number);
        }
        else
        {
            list->next = new Node;
            list->next->data = number;
            list->next->next = NULL; //MODIFIED LINE
        }

    }

void List::insert( int d)
    { 
        if( head == NULL)
        {
            head = new Node;
            head->data = d;
            head->next = NULL; //MODIFIED LINE
        }
        else
        {
            insertHelper(head, d);
        }   

    }
```

This should hopefully work.